# Regex to remove an file path suffix

Tags: regex

I'm trying, and failing, to find a Regex that will convert all of the following. Is it possible to do this with one expression rather than many for each level in the file path?:

```
 - /Folder_UK => /Folder
 - /Folder_UK/ => /Folder/
 - /Folder_UK/Folder2/ => /Folder/Folder2/
 - /FolderX/Folder_UK => /FolderX/Folder
 - /FolderX/Folder_UK/ => /FolderX/Folder/
 - /FolderX/Folder_UK/Folder2/ => /FolderX/Folder/Folder2/
```

Essentially, I just want to strip out any "_UK/"s and also a trailing '_UK' (without the forward slash).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replacing `/_UK\/?/` with a slash should work. Then you just need to take a substring if you don't want the trailing slash.

Comment: The `_UK\/?` would replace _UKFoo as well, should be `/_UK(/|$)/gm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `_UK` with empty string.

Regex:

```
_UK
```

Replament string:

```
empty string
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aU1nR4/15)